# How can I edit WooCommerce search field placeholder?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

As the subject says, I'd like to change search field placeholder from "Search Products..." to "Search Offers...". How can I do that? I tried to follow what WooCommerce says on product-searchform.php:

```
    <?php
/**
 * The template for displaying product search form
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/product-searchform.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see     https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author  WooThemes
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 2.5.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

?>
<form role="search" method="get" class="woocommerce-product-search" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
    <label class="screen-reader-text" for="woocommerce-product-search-field-<?php echo isset( $index ) ? absint( $index ) : 0; ?>"><?php _e( 'Search for:', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
    <input type="search" id="woocommerce-product-search-field-<?php echo isset( $index ) ? absint( $index ) : 0; ?>" class="search-field" placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr__( 'Search products&hellip;', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" name="s" />
    <input type="submit" value="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search', 'submit button', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product" />
</form>
```

I edited from:

```
class="search-field" placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr__( 'Search products&hellip;', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"
```

To:

```
class="search-field" placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr__( 'Search Offers&hellip;', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"
```

Nothing is changed. I've also tried to do the same thing on original WooCommerce product-searchform.php, same result.

If it's helpful, the code when I inspect element:

```
<form role="search" method="get" class="woocommerce-product-search" action="https://mywebsite.com/">
                                        <input class="search-field" placeholder="Search Products…" value="" name="s" title="Search for:" type="search">
                                        <input value="Search" type="submit">
                                        <input name="post_type" value="product" type="hidden">
                                    </form>
```

CSS:

```
/****
Search form Header
****/
.header-search {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
}

.header-search-button {
    color: #cbc7c2;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.header-search:hover .header-search-button {
    color: #fff;
}

.header-search-input {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    right: 0;
    width: 220px;
    padding: 5px;
    background: rgba(26, 26, 26, 0.9);
}

.header-search.header-search-open .header-search-input {
    display: block;
}

.header-search.header-search-open .header-search-button {
    color: #fff;
}

.header-search-input input[type=submit] {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9;
    top: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    width: 28px;
    height: 33px;
    border: none;
    background: none;
    text-indent: -9999999px;
}

.header-search-input input[type="search"] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-right: 28px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    font-family: "Roboto Condensed", sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.header-search-input:after {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 8;
    top: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    width: 20px;
    width: 33px;
    color: #999;
    font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings";
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    line-height: 1;
    line-height: 33px;
    content: "\e003";
}
```

Well, I think I'm walking on the wrong track, can you help me? Thanks in advance.

**N.B. The shocking thing remains that doesn't happen anything when I edit plugin "product-searchform.php" located in "woocommerce/templates/product-searchform.php". I've also deleted all this code:**

```
<form role="search" method="get" class="woocommerce-product-search" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
    <label class="screen-reader-text" for="woocommerce-product-search-field-<?php echo isset( $index ) ? absint( $index ) : 0; ?>"><?php _e( 'Search for:', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
    <input type="search" id="woocommerce-product-search-field-<?php echo isset( $index ) ? absint( $index ) : 0; ?>" class="search-field" placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr__( 'Search products&hellip;', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" name="s" />
    <input type="submit" value="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search', 'submit button', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product" />
</form>
```

**And nothing's happened on the website!**

How is this possibile? :O

Comment: Have you got caching enabled? something like WP Super Cache? if not, you have put the file in the wrong place on your themes folder, as overriding that way DOES work and will override it

Comment: No, I haven't caching enabled and I haven't installed any plugin like WP Super Cache. I've put file in mychildtheme/woocommerce and I've also tried to put it outside woocommerce directory, so in mychildtheme directory, no results in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code from: https://www.speakinginbytes.com/2013/10/gettext-filter-wordpress/
It uses the wordpress gettext filter, and can be used for just about anything in wordpress.

```
function my_text_strings( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
    switch ( $translated_text ) {
        case 'Search products&hellip;' :
            $translated_text = __( 'Search Offers&hellip;', 'woocommerce' );
            break;
    }
    return $translated_text;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'my_text_strings', 20, 3 );
```

Or

```
 function my_text_strings( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
    switch ( $text ) {
        case 'Search products&hellip;' :
            $text = __( 'Search Offers&hellip;', 'woocommerce' );
            break;
    }
    return $text;
 }
 add_filter( 'gettext', 'my_text_strings', 20, 3 );
```

Or even

```
add_filter('gettext', 'translate_text');
add_filter('ngettext', 'translate_text');

function translate_text($translated) {
$translated = str_ireplace('Search products&hellip;', 'Search Offers&hellip;', $translated);
return $translated;
}
```

Comment: Tried. Nothing! :(

Comment: Test it with:  switch ( $text ) instead of switch ($translated_text).  If not then try with switch ($domain)

Comment: I've tested them all and "Search Products..." is always there! I don't know what to do anymore!

Comment: You just need to change the text to the proper string: `case 'Search products&hellip;'`

Comment: Hi, David! Yes, it's what I've always done! I don't know why nothing changes!

Answer (score 0):

Solution was on the wrong text domain that, in my case, it was 'shop-isle' (theme I'm using) and not 'woocommerce'

Then, it wasn't like this:

```
 $translated_text = __( 'Search Offers&hellip;', 'woocommerce' );
```

But like this:

```
 $translated_text = __( 'Search Offers&hellip;', 'shop-isle' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code with a snippet or in the function.php.

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
   let search = document.getElementsByClassName('search-field');
   search[0].placeholder='Change this text';
 });
</script>
```

Kind regards